# android How to get pixels of textsize of textviews in another screensize and scaledDensities?

Tags: android, text-size

I'm using pixels as a unit of textsize of my textview. the problem is when I test it in different screensize and therefore scaledDensities, the ratio of the textsize to the screen is not maintained.
How can I maintain the ratio of textsize to the screen.

I'm using something like:

```
textsize = WindowSize.convertedSize(100);
textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textsize);
```

and the **convertedSize**

```
public static int convertedSize(int pixels) {
    int firstDensity = 1.5f
    int density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    float sp = Float.valueOf(pixels) / firstDensity;

    return (int) (density * sp);
}
```

Comment: Using dp/sp measure is recommended. Why do you do it with pixels?

Comment: because sp is not consistent with the ratio of the textsize to the screensize :(